# How to align text down and center with CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image]

> [![
>
>
>
>
>
> Document
>
> ## LesShop
>
> The most popular book shop for IT
>
> ```
> </body>
> </html>][1]][1]
>
> * {
>     margin: 0;
>     padding: 0;
>   }
>   
>   .context {
>     color: white;
>     background-color: #201dd6;
>     
>     width: 60%;
>     height: 900px;
>     top: 60px;
>     text-align: center;
>   }
> ```
>
> I want to align the text down and in the middle like in the photo.
> However, I couldn't make it. I also wrote my CSS codes. I'm really bad
> at CSS. Can you help me?

Comment: what do you mean by down in terms of the design aspect? what should be down like what text, all the text, etc?

Comment: I want the text in the text tag to be aligned to the middle. It currently appears in the middle and at the top. I want it to be perfectly centered.

Comment: you can use flex to do this. just add the text inside a span and do this

Comment: Please post your HTML and make a snippet!

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="context">
        <div class="text">
        <h1>PitonShop</h1>
        <p>The most popular book shop for IT</p>
        </divS>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
.context {
    color: white;
    background-color: #201dd6;
    width: 60%;
    height: 900px;
    top: 60px; /* Not used without the position property */
    text-align: center;
    display: flex; /* add this */
    align-items: center; /* add this */
    justify-content: center; /* add this */
}
```

Ctrl + Shift + i on chrome and use the developing tools :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.context {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  background-color: #201dd6;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='context'>
  <h2>LesShop</h2>
  The most popular book shop for IT
</div>
```